# How can we use API Connect to publish the existing REST API of customer?

Tags: api, ibm-api-management, apiconnect

Supposed that customer only provides me the URL end point of their existing API. They don't have swagger file for us to import the APIs.

Customer wants to use API Connect to publish their API to users to use.

I did that successfully with API Management. Now API Management is deprecated by API Connect, but that feature is still in API Connect. I failed to make it work with API Connect. How can we use API Connect to publish the existing REST API of customer not using swagger? Please shed the light. I'm greatly appreciated with your help.

Regards,
Quyen Tran

Answer (score 1):

To publish an API into an IBM API Connect catalog, and to have access to that API managed by the API Gateway, you will need a Swagger (OpenAPI) document.

If you don't have a Swagger document, you will need to author one e.g. using the API Designer or API Manager tooling.   You will need to know the URL of the existing endpoint but also the schema of any data that needs to be sent to or received from that URL.

If you made it work with IBM API Management then it should be no different with IBM API Connect.